# How to remove Malaysia keyboard on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Well, I'm from Malaysia so my region of course is Malaysia. I think the *English(Malaysia)* keyboard is added automatically so I want to remove it. But I looked in the **Settings** and **Control Panel**, both shows no result. Only the *English(United States)* and *Chinese(Simplified, China)* are in there. I cannot remove the *English(United States)* keyboard as it is default.

Comment: What do you want to replace it with?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You say you want to remove something that already isn't there.  So what is left to do?

Comment: when I press windows button + space, it's there. but now the problem just goes away mysteriously.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this stupid problem after a windows update. I think it's a bug but i managed to figure a way around it.

What you need to do is go into Time and Language --> Add a new language and select English(Malaysia). Once it is added, click English(Malaysia) and Select "Remove".

Then it will disappear from your keyboard list for good.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does not answer the original question

Comment: It did solve my problem.